# Plot a graph using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have  the date saved in csv file in this form

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aykR.png)

How can i draw a line or a bar graph for such data. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you try to parse the csv file, and then use the date as "x values" and the prices as "y values"?

Answer (score 1):

Try using something like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [xvalu1 , xvalue2 , xvalue3]
y = [yvalue1, yvalue2, yvalue3]

plt.plot(x, y)

plt.xlabel('x - axis')
plt.ylabel('y - axis')

plt.title('Line graph!')

plt.show()
```

go through this [link](https://medium.com/@allwindicaprio/plotting-graphs-using-python-and-matplotlib-f55c9b99c338) for more help.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


PATH_CSV_FILE = "Path/to/your/data.csv"

data = pandas.read_csv(PATH_CSV_FILE)
plt.plot(data["Date"], data["Price"])
plt.xlabel("Data")
plt.ylabel("Price")
plt.title("your title")
plt.show()
```